# Getting what app is opened in the foreground post Oreo

Tags: android

Is it possible to identify what App is opened in the foreground, I am looking for solutions that work from Android version 8.0 and above.

If there exists no work around, can I use the adb shell command ps via root and get the app that is being used now?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getCurrentAppPackageName(Context con){
    ActivityManager activityManager = ((ActivityManager) con.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
    if(activityManager!=null) {
        List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskInfos = activityManager.getRecentTasks(20, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
        if (recentTaskInfos != null && recentTaskInfos.size() > 0) {
            return recentTaskInfos.get(0).baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

For this to work your app needs to have the USAGE_STATS special permission which you request at runtime.

Comment: But this can only get my package name. Say i.e if whats app is opened, I want my app to detect that com.whatsapp is opened

Comment: if you run that while your app is in the foreground then it will return your app obviously. If you run it while an other app is open it will return you that app. If you want to get the history of the latest apps you just loop through the recentTaskInfos list.